# How can this array be be sorted?

Tags: sorting

I have an array with values as follows:

```
0-10
10-50
50-100
100-150
150-200
200+
```

This is actually an array of WordPress taxonomies, which WP sorts alphabetically (or ascending order of the first digit), giving me the following:

```
//notice how 50-100 gets pushed to the bottom, due to ascending order applied
0-10
10-50
100-150
150-200
200+
50-100
```

I just want to keep the order as the original array, as these are ranges for a particular situation and 50-100 at the last disturbs the UI!

Does anyone know a way to sort this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP use [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

```
$nums = array('10-50', '100-150', '0-10', '150-200', '50-100', '200+');
natsort($nums);
var_dump($nums);
```

Comment: Awesome! natsort did the job! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Parse the strings, convert them to numbers, and sort on the first number. The actual mechanics of doing that depends on your programming language. In C# you can use Linq:

```
var strings = new[] { "0-10", "10-50", "100-150", "50-100", "200+", "150-200" };
var sorted = strings.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.Split('+', '-')[0])).ToArray();
```